# Terraform snapshot not working with dynamic block for ebs_block_device

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I have created some EBS snapshots with tags like "**ResourceName -"Master-Node-1-SNAP**,**mount- /X01 or XO2"**(Only 1 value is available in the TAG), I want to use those snapshot dynamically when creating a EC2s.In my scenario, I have to create 6 master nodes and 2 Edge Nodes.

As example when I want to create Master Node 1. I want to filter the snapshots that belongs to Master node 1 and then need to find whether snapshot should mount as /x01 or /x02.

I have create sample logic which work with terraform output. but when i apply that to the EC2 module, it give an error as below

> Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an
> empty list.

My Module code as below.

```
data "aws_ebs_snapshot" "ebs_volume" {
    for_each = toset(local.pre_snapshot_ids)
    snapshot_ids = [each.value]
}

resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  count = var.instance_count
```

Dynamic Block, In snapshot_id, need to find the correct ID

```
dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = var.ebs_block_device
    content {
      delete_on_termination = lookup(ebs_block_device.value, "delete_on_termination", null)
      device_name           = ebs_block_device.value.device_name
      encrypted             = lookup(ebs_block_device.value, "encrypted", null)
      iops                  = lookup(ebs_block_device.value, "iops", null)
      kms_key_id            = lookup(ebs_block_device.value, "encrypted", null) == "true" ? var.kms_key_id : null
      # snapshot_id           = lookup(ebs_block_device.value, "snapshot_id", null)
      snapshot_id           = element([
        for val in data.aws_ebs_snapshot.ebs_volume : val.id
        if "${val.tags["mount"]}" == tostring(lookup(ebs_block_device.value, "mount", null))
        &&
        tostring(element(split("-", "${val.tags["ResourceName"]}"), length(split("-", "${val.tags["ResourceName"]}"))-2)) == "${tostring(count.index + 1)}"
      ],0)
      volume_size           = lookup(ebs_block_device.value, "volume_size", null)
      volume_type           = lookup(ebs_block_device.value, "volume_type", null)
```

Sample ebs_block_device values

```
master_ebs_block_device = [
    {
        device_name = "/dev/sdb"
        encrypted = true
        volume_type = "gp2"
        volume_size = 100
        mount = "/x01"            
        },
        {
        device_name = "/dev/sdc"
        encrypted = true
        volume_type = "gp2"
        volume_size = 500
        mount = "/x02"            
        },

]
```

Comment: What is the full error message? Where the error (which line) exactly occurs?

Comment: its for snapshot_id
snapshot_id           = element([
        for val in data.aws_ebs_snapshot.ebs_volume : val.id
        if "${val.tags["mount"]}" == tostring(lookup(ebs_block_device.value, "mount", null))
        &&
        tostring(element(split("-", "${val.tags["ResourceName"]}"), length(split("-", "${val.tags["ResourceName"]}"))-2)) == "${tostring(count.index + 1)}"
      ],0)

Comment: Please update the question with courtly format error message.